# Why do i get vue-cli errors while setting up a new project

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, yarnpkg, vue-cli-3

I have npm installed v6.9.0 ,node v10.16.0 & yarn v1.16.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

I'm following this tutorial.[tutorial link](https://medium.com/@lachlanmiller_52885/build-social-media-platform-with-the-steem-blockchain-1-vue-js-storybook-js-and-steem-js-a25bd7629a14)

While I'm initially setting up the Vue app in my directory `vuetest` and bootstrapping the app using `vue-cli`, i ran these commands:

`yarn global add vue-cli`

`vue init webpack <webpack_name>`

Vue init hanged at project description and this was a issue in github where they posted a temporary solution.
[temporary solution link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4177#issuecomment-504110700)

In the solution they said to run these commands:

1.`cd "$(dirname $(which vue))/node_modules/@vue/cli-init"`

2.`npm i inquirer@~6.3.1`

When i ran the first command i get error:

`bash: cd: /home/nishanthr/.yarn/bin/node_modules/@vue/cli-init: No such file or directory`

Output of `which vue` is:

`/home/nishanthr/.yarn/bin/vue`

Can someone tell me what's wrong and what's happening here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the new version `yarn global add @vue/cli`
[Vue Cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

Comment: I still get the error which i have mentioned(when i ran the first command) above when i try to fix it by referring to the temporary solution link.

Comment: The main problem is the temporary fix link commands not working and the errors which i got while executing them.

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#pulling-2-x-templates-legacy Maybe you need to install `@vue/cli-init`. However, you should use `vue create <my-project>` instead of `vue init`

Comment: `success Installed "@vue/cli@3.8.4" with binaries:-vue ` my cli version installed is 3.8.4 but when i run `vue create my-project` i get this ```vue create is a Vue CLI 3 only command and you are using Vue CLI 2.9.6.
  You may want to run the following to upgrade to Vue CLI 3:

  npm uninstall -g vue-cli
  npm install -g @vue/cli```

Comment: Even after i uninstall and install cli again i get the same above error when i try `vue create my-project`